# I have some problem with making program with Python turtle graphics

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I have some question about my codes.

I'm beginner of Python.
And I start making a drawing program with Python turtle graphics and upload on Github.

I want to make that when I click the left mouse button, draw the line. And when I just move my mouse without click the left button, the turtle just follow my cursor.

So I googled and find the some helpful code. But It works quite weird.
I mean, it doesn't work well.

Likes, when I click button, the turtle doesn't move. Or I can move the turtle with click th button, but the line doesn't draw...

Anyway, here are full of my codes(I think showing whole codes will be better for you...).

```py
from turtle import Screen

screen = Screen()

while True:

    print('===========================')
    print('*** Welcome to Pyint!!! ***')
    print('___________________________')
    print('*** Drawing With Turtle ***')
    print('___________________________')
    print('******* ver. 2.1.0 ********')
    print('___________________________')
    print('* Press Enter For Start!! *')
    print('___________________________')
    print('===========================')

    import turtle as t
    
    t.color('white')
    t.bgcolor('black')
    t.speed(0)
    t.shape('circle')
    t.pensize(5)
    t.shapesize(2,2,2)

    break

def colorsettings():

    while True:

        print('------------------------')
        print('**** Color Settings ****')
        print('------------------------')

        chgpencolor = t.color(str(input('Color?:')))
        savecolorsettings = str(input('Save the color settings? [y/n]:'))

        if savecolorsettings == 'n':
            continue
        elif savecolorsettings == 'y':
            print('-----------------------')
            print('******** Saved ********')
            print('-----------------------')
            break

def thicknesssettings():
        
        while True:

            print('------------------------')
            print('** Thickness Settings **')
            print('------------------------')

            chgpenthickness = t.pensize(int(input('Thickness?:')))
            savethicknesssettings = str(input('Save the thickness settings? [y/n]:'))

            if savethicknesssettings == 'n':
                continue
            elif savethicknesssettings == 'y':
                print('-----------------------')
                print('******** Saved ********')
                print('-----------------------')
                break

Moving, Dragging = range(2) # Codes about control the turtle start here.

def move_pen(x, y):
    if state != Moving:
        return

    onmove(screen, None)
    t.penup()
    t.setheading(t.towards(x, y))
    t.goto(x, y)
    onmove(screen, move_pen)

def click_pen(x, y):
    global state

    t.onclick(None)
    onmove(screen, None)

    t.onrelease(release_handler)
    t.ondrag(drag_handler)

    state = Dragging

def release_handler(x, y):
    global state

    t.onrelease(None)
    t.ondrag(None)

    t.onclick(click_pen)
    onmove(screen, move_pen)

    state = Moving

def drag_handler(x, y):
    if state != Dragging:
        return

    t.ondrag(None)
    t.pendown()
    t.setheading(t.towards(x, y))
    t.goto(x, y)
    t.ondrag(drag_handler)

def onmove(self, fun, add=None):

    if fun is None:
        self.cv.unbind('<Motion>')
    else:
        def eventfun(event):
            fun(self.cv.canvasx(event.x) / self.xscale, -self.cv.canvasy(event.y) / self.yscale)
        self.cv.bind('<Motion>', eventfun, add)

onmove(screen, move_pen)
t.onclick(click_pen) # End of codes about control the turtle

state  = Moving

while True:
    
    ipt = str(input())

    if ipt == 'pencolor':
        colorsettings()
    elif ipt == 'penthickness':
        thicknesssettings()
    elif ipt == 'h':
        t.goto(0,0)
    elif ipt == 'c':
        t.clear()
    elif ipt == 'z':
        t.undo()
    elif ipt =='pu':
        t.penup()
    elif ipt =='pd':
        t.pendown()
    elif ipt == 'gg':
        print('Are you really want to close the program? [y/n]')
    elif ipt == 'n':
        continue
    elif ipt == 'y':
        break
```

This is my first time here. Also my first question.
If my question wad rude or unkind for you, I want to say sorry.

Thanks :)

Comment: What's the point of a `while` loop that always breaks?

Comment: You should generally have `import` statements at top-level.

Comment: Umm.. I know that 'while' need when I end up for while loop.

Comment: I'm talking about the `while` loop that prints the welcome message and initializes the turtle. Why is that a loop?

Comment: And you said that 'import' statements have at top-level
Does that mean I 'd better type all 'import' at the top of codes?

p.s. Thank you for your comments!!

Comment: Oh, I got it...

I think you're right. I don't need while loop at the welcome message. Thx

Comment: They don't *have* to be, but should be unless you have a good reason otherwise.

Comment: All right! Thank you for your kindness.

Comment: This seems to work OK for me.